# Strings in ANSI C

Tags: c

This is the third program in C language.
This program is to demonstrate string concept.

From study I know that string at its end has a null character '\0' to terminate the string.

I wrote that code :

```
main()
{
      char  name[8];

      strcpy(name, "Mahmoud");
      printf("The contents of name are %s\n", name);
      getchar();
}
```

In this code I declare array of type char to save string in it. My name "Mahmoud" is 7 chars and I declare name with size 8 which is 7 for "Mahmoud" and 1 for '\0', and it works correctly.

But in the following code:

```
main()
{
      char  name[8];

      strcpy(name, "MahmoudEmam");
      printf("The contents of name are %s\n", name);
      getchar();
}
```

When I display name the output is "MahmoudEmam", although the size of name is 8.

How does it do ?

Comment: Simple. Reading/writing past the end of an array is undefined behaviour. It's not required to crash.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just stomped out the contents of some memory that you didn't mean to.

Comment: Undefined behaviour, which in this case behaves as if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact you see the full name displayed is undefined behavior. Basically, you are copying more than 7 characters and a terminating 0 (total of 8 characters) into storage reserved only for 7 characters and a terminating 0.

It just happens to work, but could as easily cause your program to crash.

This is why C is considered a lower level programming language, or, as the phrase used to go many years ago, a high level assembly programming language.

You the programmer have to check the length of the copy operation's target, using a construct like `sizeof(name)`, and make sure what you are copying does not override that space. You must also keep in mind for
string termination, enough space + 1 to account for the terminating '\0'.

Don't forget that using sizeof with a string allocated with malloc will return a value of 4 for a 32-bit pointer, or the pointer length of your hardware. In that case, you'll have to rely on strlen to get the buffer length, or store what size was used to malloc the string.

Finally, when passing a string pointer to a function, writing the function to have a buffer length is very helpful. You cannot get the true buffer length. strlen only returns the string length, not the buffer size actually pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: don't forget that when using sizeof() with a string that has been allocated with malloc, will return a size of 4 bytes.

Comment: And won't work inside a function where the string is passed in.

Comment: @chris Which is why when I used to write a lot C, I took a page from PL/I and VMS and used "descriptor" mindset that would at least provide a pointer to the string, and a length of the buffer holding it. A lot of us who like C missed that ability to tell the function how long a buffer was associated with a string pointer.

Answer (score 5):

C does not perform any array bounds checking (maybe with C11...). You are writing past the end of your array : it is an undefined behavior  (anything can happen).

Comment: Lucky? I'd call it the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You are being lucky in this case. What's happening is that you have allocated enough memory on the stack for a 7-letter string (+ one for `'\0'`), but you are writing beyond it.

C does not detect reading/writing out of array boundaries for you.

So what's happening is that, you are writing over the rest of the array, destroying whatever else there may be. In a larger program, you will most likely encounter a crash.

This is a good example of why you should learn to use [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy), but remember that `strncpy` doesn't add the terminating `'\0'` if the buffer is full and you should do it yourself. A code like this would do:

```
strncpy(name, "the text of your string, whatever it is", sizeof(name));
name[sizeof(name) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: strncpy isn't intended to automatically add \0 to the end of our char arrays or something like that. It's intended to write fixed-width strings, which is not the case here.
He could use strncpy, but to be safe the right way is to call strncpy with sizeof(array)-1, and right after calling it, setting the last char in the array to \0.
`strncpy(name, "MahmoudEmam", sizeof(name) - 1);
name[sizeof(name) - 1] = '\0';`

Comment: @spidey, definitely. It's all in the man page that I linked to.

Comment: `strncpy(name, "MahmoudEmam", sizeof(name));` will not add the '\0', it's behavior will be exactly the same as `memcpy(name, "MahmoudEmam", sizeof(name));` when the third parameter is lesser than strlen of the second parameter.

Comment: @spidey, I never said it adds the `'\0'`. I linked the man page and I expected the OP would go read it. If it's such a big deal to you that I didn't say it, I'll put it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking undefined behaviour. You can't rely on that because it works.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered, but if I may, I'd like to refine it a bit.

If you notice, `strcpy()` does not take buffer length as a parameter. That is because it trusts you, the user, to take care not to overflow the destination buffer.

There is no constrain in C as to what data you can place in what location in memory. That is at the same time a powerfully tool and a dangerous one, if poorly used.

When you call `printf()`, it goes through the buffer you provide until it finds the first 0 and prints everything. If you provide a random buffer, it will print gibberish. In the case of the program you wrote, you provided a buffer with the string you copied there. Even though you breached the buffer, the program still managed to find its way and print it because it does not even know the memory is corrupted.

Buffer overflows are one of the hardest bugs you can find. They will often affect parts of the program not related to the module causing the corruption itself and often can take long to have their effect felt. So you should take great care not to cause such a bug!